# Display a message (e.g. "loading") while an embedly-card is loading

Tags: php, embedly

Embedly cards are great. But often they load slowly which means that the user is seeing a blank area before the card renders. It might make the user think there won't be any  content appearing in that blank area where embledy-card is going to show. How can I show a loading animated gif or just a plain text message while the card is loading?